# Getting latest image from imageCollection using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to get the last image available in an image collection but I can't find any function that works.

I've tried also to sort the collection in the reverse order, but it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD");

//get the first image and its date
var firstimg = chirps.limit(1, 'system:time_start').first();
var firstdate = ee.Date(firstimg.get('system:time_start'))
print(firstdate);

//now I try to get the latest...

chirps.sort('system:time_start', false);
var lastimg=chirps.limit(1, 'system:time_start').first();
print(ee.Date(lastimg.get('system:time_start')));
```

How can I get the last image available and its date in order to know which is the last date available?

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies in 2 places.

```
chirps.sort('system:time_start', false);
```

You `.sort()`, but don't actually place the result in a variable.  (so nothing happens)

```
var lastimg=chirps.limit(1, 'system:time_start').first();
```

The second, is when you use the `.limit()` function, you added the property.  Which is also a sort...  and by not putting a `false`, it went with default `true`.

Change your code as such and it will work.

```
var lastimg=chirps.limit(1, 'system:time_start', false).first();
```

Result:

> sorted
>
> Date (2019-08-26 00:00:00)
>
> type: Date
>
> value: 1566777600000

Answer (score 2):

found it:

```
var range = chirps.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"])
print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')))
```