# Finding out when image added to ImageCollection of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

I am trying to figure out when an image (or observation in general) was uploaded to Earth Engine. I have a script that gives me the most recent image date, but as far as I can see this refers specifically to the image acquisition date (i.e. as seen in `system:index:` and `system:time_start[end]:`).

Ultimately, I'd like to take an image collection (e.g. Sentinel 2 TOA over 6 months) and determine both the mean time between images plus the average time difference between the image acquisition itself and the processed image uploaded to GEE.

I've checked on answers at [Earth Engine get latest image from an imageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338525/earth-engine-get-latest-image-from-an-imagecollection) and linked below.

Here is a sample script, with the function coming from [Get all dates of image collection when it was created/loaded on sentinel 2 dataset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293406/get-all-dates-of-image-collection-when-it-was-created-loaded-on-sentinel-2-datas). The list of satellites is the full list I eventually want to run these statistics on.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([95.219623, 23.029892]).buffer(300000)

var sat =
  ["COPERNICUS/S1_GRD",         //sentinel 1 SAR-GRD cband (2014-10-03) 4825 features
    "COPERNICUS/S2",            //sentinel 2 TOA Level 1C (2015-06-23) 7425 features
    "COPERNICUS/S2_SR",         //sentinel2 SR Level 2A (2017-03-28) 2810 features
    "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA",  //landsat8 TOA (April 2013) 2324 features
    "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR",   //landsat8 SR (April 2013) 2324 features
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GQ",        //modis 250m (2000-02-24) 33420 features
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GA"         //modis 500m (2000-02-24) 33400 features aka rows in table
];

var coll = ee.ImageCollection(sat[1])
.filterDate('2020-10-01', '2020-10-31')
.filterBounds(pt)
print('sample image', coll.first())

var get_dates = function(collection, month, year) {
  var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
                           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))

  return ee.List(filtered.toList(filtered.size()).map(function(img){
    return ee.Image(img).date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')
  }))
}

var dates = get_dates(coll, 10, 2020).distinct();
var num = dates.size();
print(dates)
print('Max date from image.date()', dates.get(num.subtract(1)))

print('current date time', ee.Date(Date.now()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after playing around a bit more, plus with help from Simon on the GEE Developers page [Ingestion datetime for landsat scenes](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/rkQXGB0wcRU) (see post from 6 Nov. 2020). He mentioned that the current ingestion delay from when USGS/ESA posts images and when they're uploaded to GEE is the following:

- Landsat: ~18h
- Sentinel-1: ~36h
- Sentinel-2 L1: ~12h
- Sentinel-2 L2: ~18h

This alone answers the broad aspect of my question, but I also got the GEE script to report this and the other metrics I specified from my question in the console. One thing to consider in this script (as illuminated by Simon in the linked website above) is that for L8 ingestion time I use the last date in the full product id, then add 24 hours to ensure I've captured the average ingestion time.

The script here will report the wanted parameters for a specified point, satellite sensor, and date timeframe. The `.multiply(1000)` is to have a common time in microseconds.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Step 1: Define functions
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// get specific ImageCollection and filter
var getImgColl = function(i, focalPoint, dateStart, dateEnd){
  return ee.ImageCollection(sat[i])
  .filterDate(dateStart, dateEnd)
  .filterBounds(pt);
};

// get dates from IC into list
var get_dates = function(collection) {
  return ee.List(collection.toList(collection.size()).map(function(img){
    return ee.Image(img).date().format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  }));
};

// time conversions
var microSecToHour = function(aNum){
    return aNum.multiply(ee.Number(2.77778).multiply(ee.Number(10).pow(-10)));
};
  
var microSecToDays = function(aNum){
  return aNum.multiply(ee.Number(1.15741).multiply(ee.Number(10).pow(-11)));
};

// full time difference retrieval function
var getDates = function(collection, list_of_dates, satellite){
  var findDates = function(x){
    var l8 = i == 3 || x == 4; print('is l8?', l8);
    
    //We look at an image and its previous one for comparison. This way,
    //in a collection we have a value for every image save for the first.
    var origDate = ee.Date(ee.Date(list_of_dates.get(ee.Number(x))).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
    var origImg = collection.filterDate(origDate, origDate.advance(1, "day")).first();
  
    var prevDate = ee.Date(ee.Date(list_of_dates.get(ee.Number(x).subtract(1))).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
    var prevImg = collection.filterDate(prevDate, prevDate.advance(1, "day")).first();
  
    // L8 has a different variable for ingestion time, so it needs its own
    // function and if statement
    var l8Calc = function(str){
      var stringNum = ee.String(str).rindex('2020');
      var dateTest = ee.String(str).slice(stringNum, stringNum.add(8));
      var finalDate = ee.Date.parse('YYYYMMdd', dateTest)
      .advance(1, 'day').millis().multiply(1000);
      return finalDate;
    };
    
    var origIngest = ee.Algorithms.If(l8,
    l8Calc(origImg.get('LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID')),
    ee.Number(origImg.get('system:version'))); 
    
    var prevIngest = ee.Algorithms.If(l8,
    l8Calc(prevImg.get('LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID')),
    ee.Number(prevImg.get('system:version')));
  
    var origObserve = ee.Number(origImg.get('system:time_end')).multiply(1000);
    var prevObserve = ee.Number(prevImg.get('system:time_end')).multiply(1000); 

    // difference in time btwn observation and ingestion (hours)
    var time_diffHour = microSecToHour(ee.Number(origIngest).subtract(origObserve));
  
   // difference in time between first and next image observation (days)
   var time_diffObs = microSecToDays(origObserve.subtract(prevObserve));
  
   // difference btwn this and previous image ingestion (days)
   var time_diffIng = microSecToDays(ee.Number(origIngest).subtract(prevIngest));
  
   var output = ee.Feature(pt,
   {date: origDate, obsToIngHours: time_diffHour, obsDiffDays: time_diffObs,
      ingDiffDays: time_diffIng
    });
    return output;
  };
  return findDates;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Step 2. Define the necessary variables (pt, i, and dates)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// define initial variables
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([95.219623, 23.029892]).buffer(10);
//var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([-78.664414, 35.769955]).buffer(10);
var i = 3;
var date_start = '2020-02-20';
var date_end = '2020-10-20';

var sat =
  ["COPERNICUS/S1_GRD",         //sentinel 1 SAR-GRD cband (2014-10-03) >4800 features
    "COPERNICUS/S2",            //sentinel 2 TOA Level 1C (2015-06-23) >7400 features
    "COPERNICUS/S2_SR",         //sentinel2 SR Level 2A (2017-03-28) >2800 features
    "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA",  //landsat8 TOA (April 2013) >2300 features
    "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR",   //landsat8 SR (April 2013) >2300 features
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GQ",        //modis 250m (2000-02-24) >33000 features
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GA"         //modis 500m (2000-02-24) >33000 features
];

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Step 3: Run the functions (results are in the properties)
//          `numList` is defined in order to focus on images in the collection
//          except for the first.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
var coll = getImgColl(i, pt, date_start, date_end);
//print(coll);
var dateList = get_dates(coll).distinct().sort();
var numList = ee.List.sequence(1, ee.Number(dateList.size().subtract(1)));
print('dates', dateList);
print('numList', numList);

var testFull = numList.map(getDates(coll, dateList));
var testFullFC = ee.FeatureCollection(testFull);
print('output FeatureColl', testFullFC);
```